# Storing the results of a SQLAlchemy query to merge into another session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy-based tool for selectively copying data between two different databases for testing purposes. I use the `merge()` function to take model objects from one session and store them in another session. I'd like to be able to store the source objects in some intermediate form and then `merge()` them at some later point in time.

It seems like there are a few options to accomplish this:

- Exporting `DELETE`/`INSERT` SQL statements. Seems pretty straightforward, I think I can get SQLAlchemy to give me the `INSERT` statements, and maybe even the `DELETE`s.
- Exproting the data to a SQLite database file with the same (or similar) schema, that could then be read in as a source at a later point in time.
- Serializing the data in some manner and then reading them back into memory for the merge. I don't know if SQLAlchemy has something like this built-in or not. I'm not sure what the challenges would be in rolling this myself.

Has anyone tackled this problem before? If so, what was your solution?

**EDIT:** I found a tool built on top of SQLAlchemy called [dataset](http://dataset.readthedocs.org/en/latest/freezefile.html) that provides the freeze functionality I'm looking for, but there seems to be no corresponding *thaw* functionality for restoring the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it before, but the dogpile caching techniques described in the documentation might be what you want. This allows you to query to and from a cache using the SQLAlchemy API:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/examples.html#module-examples.dogpile_caching

Comment: I think this will work, although I still have not had time to implement it yet. Thanks!